# execute ssh with command su and keep log in

Tags: linux, ssh

I have a server where I have 2 users, one for ssh access and the other one for command execution, I want to create a command that use ssh, the **su** command and I want to keep the session alive, I try this:

```
ssh -t user@ip 'echo password | su superuser; bash -l'
```

It appears to enter but finished the session immediately, if I don't use the **su** command it works:

```
ssh -t user@ip 'echo password; bash -l'
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Why would you run `bash`? `su` executes a shell itself. And `echo password` would fail any security audit.

Comment: is only for my local files, I want to execute a file that do all the steps between the ssh user and the super user, I don't want to do it manually